# I get INTERNAL_POWER_ERROR BSOD

Tags: bsod

My PC shuts down itself after I turn it on, so I have to turn it on again and then it works,and the minidumps show the INTERNAL_POWER_ERROR,and I also got a few INTERNAL_POWER_ERROR BSODs.
And I got a MEMORY_MANAGEMENT BSOD once.

What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Please see below.  This is an incompatible driver error or possibly a small hibernation file.

Disable hibernation and then run the manufacturer's Driver Update App and update all drivers including BIOS and Chipset (if chipset exists)

https://windowsreport.com/internal_power_error-windows-10/

> Blue Screen of Death errors are often caused by outdated or
> incompatible drivers, and in order to fix this error, we strongly
> advise you to update all drivers on your PC.
>
> Many users reported that INTERNAL POWER ERROR occurs due to the small
> size of the hibernation file, and the only solution is to increase its
> size. See how you can do that in our guide below

.